# Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'chapati' for column 'food_item' at row

Tags: laravel

am trying to save food item in a restaurant called foods

```
        $food=new Food;
        $food->restaurant_id=$request->get('restaurant_id');
        $food->price=$request->input('price');
        $food->food_item=$request->input('food_item'); 
        $food->save();
```

am getting the error above

Comment: You better show us your `foods` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your **Food** model has possibly a foreign key to a **FoodItem** model.  You may have set up your database to allow for a `food_item` foreign key for the relationship to work.

Take a look at your migration and relationships on the **Food** model.  I suspect it is looking for an integer foreign key to match up with the FoodItem model, and what was coming in from the `$request` object was a string, 'chapati', which caused the database error.  Or possibly it was just a mistake when you created the `foods` database and was supposed to be a string.  The "datetime" thing in the error message leans toward **likely just a mistake at the database creation time**, where you may have entered the `food_item` as a datetime type.

To correct, change the database to a **string** for `food_item`, or change the form to allow for the `id` of a **FoodItem** to come in to the `$request` object (or a datetime if that is really what you wanted).